# How to catch only the row you enter in a text area before pressing ENTER key in JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an example and want I want to do now is to catch the value of some rows in a text area after pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
I have detected the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press using this JQuery function:

```
$('#output').keypress(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var read_lines = $('#output').val().split("\n");
        alert(read_lines);  
    }

});
```

and I try to catch the values in the `#output` text area using this:

```
var read_lines = $('#output').val().split("\n");
    alert(read_lines);
```

but it catch all the text in the text area not only the one I insert before pressing Enter key.

Can you please help me?

Here is my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/orsina/k9e4nhnw/).

Comment: I have tried catching the last element like `alert(read_lines[read_lines.length-1]); ` , but what I have other rows after?

Comment: It's not actually a newline character, console.log is showing '↵'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an array so you want the last one

alert(read_lines[read_lines.length-1]);

Comment: Thanks. I thought this before and finaly I solved this in that way because I removed all the rows after read statement